# Magento 2 : Add Extra Fee and Extra Fee Tax Into Tax Amount

Tags: magento2, tax, extrafee

I am working on **Magento 2** module where I need extra fee as well as tax of extra fees which need to add into tax amount of quote total.

If anyone knows how to do, comment please.

Thank in advance